# How to pass MenuItem as command parameter for its child control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have something like below. For `MenuItem`, here I am passing an object of that `MenuItem` as a `CommandParameter`. This works fine for me. My `MenuItem` holds a `RadioButton` and I want to use the MenuItem `CommandParameter` value for this `RadioButton`. Could anyone please help me how to do this. Thanks in Advance.

```
<MenuItem Header="Name"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
      <MenuItem.Icon>
           <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="3"
                        IsChecked="True"
                        GroupName="sort"
                        Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="..." />
      </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Now `Command` is executing only when I select the `MenuItem`. I want to do the same when user selects the `RadioButton` also. Below is the code which I am using for this.

```
public void OnSortCommandExecuted(object menuItem)
{
   MenuItem menu = menuItem as MenuItem;
   if (menu != null)
   {
      ((RadioButton)menu.Icon).IsChecked = !((RadioButton)menu.Icon).IsChecked;
      this.eAggregator.GetEvent<ImagesSortedEvent>().Publish(menu.Header.ToString());    
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to bind RadioButton Command with SortCommand? If yes why not to bind like you did for MenuItem. They both share same DataContext, so it can be bind to RadioButton as well.

Comment: @RohitVats how I can pass MenuItem as command parameter for Radio button?

Comment: First of all it's not a good approach to send UI component as CommandParameter to ViewModel. Second RadioButton doesn't lie in same visual tree as that of menuItem. Hence, you cannot access directly you have to put some kind of hacks to get it (I can provide hack if you want) but I think it would be nice if you post code that what are you trying to acheive by passing MenuItem. May be there is some better approach to solve that.

Comment: @RohitVats I have updated the question with the code behind

Comment: Why not to bind `IsChecked` with some property where your command resides. Then you can simply use that property from your code and no need to pass CommandParameter. Also can do same with `Header` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments as well, it's not a good practise to pass on UI component as `CommandParameter` to ViewModel since ViewModel shouldn't know about View.

I would suggest you to have proper binding in ViewModel. **Create a `bool` property in ViewModel and bind with `IsChecked` DP of radioButton**. That ways you don't have to pass any `CommandParameter` from View, simply check the status of bool property from command execute method.

---

> Now, that why `MenuItem` can't be accessed from RadioButton?

RadioButton **doesn't lie in same Visual tree** as that of MenuItem.

So, you can't use `RelativeSource` to travel upto MenuItem. Also `ElementName` binding won't work here since this to work both elements should lie in same Visual Tree.

You might find over net to use `x:Reference` in such cases where two elements doesn't lie in same Visual tree but that won't work here since it will create cyclic dependency.

Last thing, you have to resort with it to use `Freezable` class object to hold an instance of MenuItem and use that resource in your bindings.

**First** of all you need to define class deriving from `Freezable`:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
                                     typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

and you can use it from XAML like this to pass MenuItem:

```
    <MenuItem Header="Name"
              x:Name="menuItem"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy"
                                Data="{Binding Source={x:Reference menuItem}}"/>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <RadioButton VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="3"
                         IsChecked="True"
                         GroupName="sort"
                         Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding Data.CommandParameter,
                                              Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
```

Ofcourse you need to declare `local` namespace in XAML.

**PS - I would still insist to use first approach to define proper bindings in ViewModel.**

---

**UPDATE**

If `MenuItem` is placed under `ContextMenu`, then `RelativeSource` binding won't be possible. Approach described above will work in that case.

But in case you are placing MenuItem directly as child of some control (like Menu), `RelativeSource` binding will work:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter,
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}}"
```

Comment: This is an awesome explanation Rohit :), You mentioned that Radio button not lie in the same VisualTee of that MenuItem. But in snoop it is showing as a child.

Comment: I was assuming you are placing MenuItem in ContextMenu. Isn't it?

Comment: No, I placed it in Menu

Comment: See the update in answer. Try using `RelativeSource`.